# Random studdering when using UIScrollView together with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

I am experiencing studdering/lag while scrolling.

It only appears on iPhone5 och very rarely on iPhone 5s.
It only appears while holding you finger down, not while the scrollview is decelerating. 
It appears very random, but once it starts lagging it always continues for a while.

It may be triggered by jumping out to the home screen and back again a few times (sometimes it works for a while, and sometimes the studdering appear amost all the time). It is occuring, as I said, very randomly so If you try this example project and dont see any studdering, please be patient and try some more.

The example project is based on the SpriteKit game template, and I tried to make as few changes to it as possible to make it easier to debug.

Example project: https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollStudderingExample

I am in contact with Apple support about this, but so far they have only mentioned that they will send it to the technicians that work on SpriteKit and get back to me.

I have been struggling with this problem for maybe one year now, so if someone comes up with a real solution to why this is happening I will cry with happiness.

Comment: Are you using a scroll view to implement a moving camera system? Or is this part of a UIKit Main Menu or something else?

Comment: This is more of a scrolling menu. If there would be an alternative to UIScrollView in SpriteKit I would love to use that, but there isnt one. The only ones out there are NO WAY near the native feeling of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Did you do any profiling in instruments?

Comment: Nope, but thanks for the advice, I will do that right away. Don't really know what to look for, but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Sven No luck. I couldn't find anything special but I am not very familiar with the profiler. Only thing that caught my attention was that when the studdering appeared, the updating/rendering of the scrollbar also started to flash. So it feels like the UIKit-part is starting to lag for some reason.

Comment: So did you hear anything from the technicians that work on SpriteKit?

Comment: @Sebastian Nope, not yet. I doubt that I ever will. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea: Have you tried decoupling the `scrollViewDidScroll` method from the animation? (Like "debouncing" scroll events in Javacript.)

I can't test it right now and am not saying that this is good practice, but I'm curious if this fixes the problem…

**Abstract example:**

A global variable somewhere:

```
CGPoint globalVar;
```

In the ViewController:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    globalVar = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

In the SKScene:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

     spriteToScroll.position = globalVar;
}
```

Comment: Did get that suggestion from a fellow developer, but it didnt work for me. I tried it now again, and still no luck. Here is a branch with my added code to show: https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollStudderingExample/tree/decoupled

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am going test it on a device. I really want to use a scrollview for an app. But neither the CCScrollview nor any other solution comes close to your UIScrollView + SpriteKit solution.